# Is it possible to combine the two fonts (fouriernc & gfsartemisia-euler)?

Tags: fonts, equations, text, math-fonts, euler

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{gfsartemisia-euler}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
Experience the font

$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}x^{2}dx+\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k} y_{i}=1$
\end{document}
```

[image: I want to be writing by (euler) and the equations by (fouriernc)]

Comment: Welcome to the site! I’m not entirely clear in what way you want to combine them.

Comment: The image you link implies that the problem is a missing `\Delta`, but there isn’t one in the source of the MWE you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that this means that you want fouriernc in math and the `gfsartemisia-euler` as text.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{artemisiaeuler}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
Experience the font

$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}x^{2}dx+\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k} y_{i}=1$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanh you very much. I really appreciate your help.